# Mean and Standard Deviation of samples consisting of all $0$'s or all $1$'s

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, means

Set of numbers $\ x_1, \ldots, x_m , y_1, \ldots, y_n $ where $\ x_i=0 $ for  $i = 1,\ldots, m$ and $\ y_i=1 $ for $i = 1,\ldots, n$

Show that mean $M$ of this set is given by $\frac{n}{m+n}$ and the standard deviation $S$ by $\frac{ \sqrt{mn}} {m+n} $

I know the definitions of the mean and standard deviation and how to get them but Im really stuck at that question

Comment: sorry I edited y=1 is true now you can check

Comment: Hint: How many ones do you have? How many zeros? Try specific values of $m$ and $n$.

Comment: I deducted the the result that mean is 1 and standart deviation is 0 but I cant show in formula just like that

Comment: The mean is most certainly not $1$. Try computing it again, with specific choices of $m$ and $n$.

Comment: For example, suppose $m=3,n=2.$ Then the list of numbers is $0,0,0,1,1.$ What is the mean of those five numbers? What is the standard deviation?

Comment: @DavidK. Mean is OK. Puzzled about SD: For data (0,0,0,1,1), the usual def'n of sample SD gives 0.5477226, but $\sqrt{6}/5 = 0.4898979.$ For data (0,1) SD is 0.7071068 which doesn't match $1/2.$ Done with this pending clarification.

Comment: Perhaps you're supposed to assume this is the entire population and do a population standard deviation rather than a sample standard deviation. Then you would get $\sqrt6/5$ for $0,0,0,1,1.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample variance of observations denoted $x_i$ is $$S^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x)^3}{n-1}
= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\; -\; (\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)^2/n}{n-1}.$$

The middle member of the equation is the definition and the last member is 
sometimes called the 'computational formula' (easily deduced from the definition). Is that the definition of $S$ you're using?

Notice that for $x_i \equiv 0,$ one has $\sum_{i-1}^m x_i = \sum_{i-1}^m x_i^2 = 0.$

Also,  for $y_i \equiv 1,$ one has $\sum_{i-1}^n y_i = \sum_{i-1}^n y_i^2 = n.$

Put it all together, and you should be off to a good start--provided I have
properly interpreted a somewhat vague question.

Answer (score -1):

Calculate the zero, first and second moments
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum 1 = ? \\
\sum z_j = ? \\
\sum z_j^2 = ? \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Then use the formulea
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mu&=&\frac{\sum z}{\sum 1 } \\
\sigma^2 &=& \frac{\sum z^2}{\sum 1 }- \frac{(\sum z)^2}{(\sum 1)^2 }.
\end{eqnarray*}

> $\sum 1 = n+m \,\,\, \sum z_j = n \,\,\,  \sum z_j^2 = n $